# LINQ select clause type confusion

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following model

```
namespace Models
{
  [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Table(Name = "RegionTable")]
  public class Region
  {
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column]
    public string OrchardRoleID { get; set; }
  }
}
```

and i want to select all regions and return it via a list of Region model objects.

Why is this working

```
var lQuery = from r in lDBContext.Regions new Models.Region { ID = r.ID, Name = r.Name };

var l = lQuery.ToList();
```

but the following is not

```
var lQuery = from r in lDBContext.Regions select r;

var l = lQuery.ToList();
```

as it throws a

```
 Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
```

exception?

Comment: What is **lDBContext**?

Comment: @Maciej Los: **lDBContext** is of type `System.Data.Linq.DataContext`, the issue is already solved, see answer of Smog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because

```
public string OrchardRoleID { get; set; }
```

i suppose that this is a `int` in your database
in your fist example it works because you're omitting that field

Comment: Yep, just discovered it too while writing `var lQuery = from r in lDBContext.Regions new Models.Region { ID = r.ID, Name = r.Name, OrchardRoleID = r.OrchardRoleID };` as it throws the same exception. Anyway, thanks for your answer.